# Unable to join peer0.org2 to channel - endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org2.example.com: connection refused

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to build a network with 2 Orgs with 1 peer each and try to join them to a common channel. All cryptogen artifacts are generated as expected. Please find the yaml files below,

**crypto-config.yaml**

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: "Orderer"
    Domain: "example.com"
    Specs:
      - Hostname: "orderer"
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: "Org1"
    Domain: "org1.example.com"
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1
  - Name: "org2"
    Domain: "org2.example.com"
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

**configtx.yaml**

```
Organizations:
  - Name: "OrdererOrg"
    ID: "OrdererMSP"
    MSPDir: "crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp"
  - Name: "Org1MSP"
    ID: "Org1MSP"
    MSPDir: "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp"
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: "peer0.org1.example.com"
        Port: 7051
  - Name: "org2MSP"
    ID: "org2MSP"
    MSPDir: "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp"
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: "peer0.org2.example.com"
        Port: 10201
Application:
  Organizations: null
Orderer:
  OrdererType: "solo"
  Addresses:
    - "orderer.example.com:7050"
  BatchTimeout: "2s"
  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: "99 MB"
    PreferredMaxBytes: "512 KB"
  Kafka:
    Brokers:
      - "127.0.0.1:9092"
  Organizations: null
Profiles:
  OneOrgOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
      OrdererType: "solo"
      Addresses:
        - "orderer.example.com:7050"
      BatchTimeout: "2s"
      BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: "99 MB"
        PreferredMaxBytes: "512 KB"
      Kafka:
        Brokers:
          - "127.0.0.1:9092"
      Organizations:
        - Name: "OrdererOrg"
          ID: "OrdererMSP"
          MSPDir: "crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp"
    Consortiums:
      SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
          - Name: "Org1MSP"
            ID: "Org1MSP"
            MSPDir: "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp"
            AnchorPeers:
              - Host: "peer0.org1.example.com"
                Port: 7051
          - Name: "org2MSP"
            ID: "org2MSP"
            MSPDir: "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp"
            AnchorPeers:
              - Host: "peer0.org2.example.com"
                Port: 10201
  OneOrgChannel:
    Consortium: "SampleConsortium"
    Application:
      Organizations:
        - Name: "Org1MSP"
          ID: "Org1MSP"
          MSPDir: "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp"
          AnchorPeers:
            - Host: "peer0.org1.example.com"
              Port: 7051
        - Name: "org2MSP"
          ID: "org2MSP"
          MSPDir: "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp"
          AnchorPeers:
            - Host: "peer0.org2.example.com"
              Port: 10201
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "2"
networks:
  basic: null
services:
  ca.org1.example.com:
    image: "hyperledger/fabric-ca"
    environment:
      - "FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server"
      - "FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1"
      - "FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
      - "FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/692b679f21458a2283135a063617ebbcca9537e6e025754c34fd573b1bc07ce3_sk"
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: "sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'"
    volumes:
      - "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config"
    container_name: "ca.org1.example.com"
    networks:
      - "basic"
  ca.org2.example.com:
    image: "hyperledger/fabric-ca"
    environment:
      - "FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server"
      - "FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2"
      - "FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem"
      - "FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/f19ec77442abb428ab593933bca9e4c61b86f460d40c342ecb74540068190318_sk"
    ports:
      - "8054:8054"
    command: "sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'"
    volumes:
      - "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config"
    container_name: "ca.org2.example.com"
    networks:
      - "basic"
  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: "orderer.example.com"
    image: "hyperledger/fabric-orderer"
    environment:
      - "FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info"
      - "ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0"
      - "ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file"
      - "ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block"
      - "ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP"
      - "ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp"
    working_dir: "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer"
    command: "orderer"
    ports:
      - "7050:7050"
    volumes:
      - "./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx"
      - "./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer"
      - "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1"
      - "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg2"
    networks:
      - "basic"
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: "peer0.org1.example.com"
    image: "hyperledger/fabric-peer"
    environment:
      - "CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com"
      - "FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info"
      - "CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info"
      - "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP"
      - "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/"
      - "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051"
      - "CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic"
      - "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB"
      - "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984"
      - "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME="
      - "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD="
    working_dir: "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric"
    command: "peer node start"
    ports:
      - "7051:7051"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/:/host/var/run/"
      - "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer"
      - "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users"
      - "./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx"
    depends_on:
      - "orderer.example.com"
      - "couchdb"
    networks:
      - "basic"
  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: "peer0.org2.example.com"
    image: "hyperledger/fabric-peer"
    environment:
      - "CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com"
      - "FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info"
      - "CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info"
      - "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org2MSP"
      - "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/"
      - "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:10201"
      - "CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic"
      - "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB"
      - "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984"
      - "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME="
      - "CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD="
    working_dir: "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric"
    command: "peer node start"
    ports:
      - "10201:10201"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/:/host/var/run/"
      - "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer"
      - "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users"
      - "./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx"
    depends_on:
      - "orderer.example.com"
      - "couchdb"
    networks:
      - "basic"
  couchdb:
    container_name: "couchdb"
    image: "hyperledger/fabric-couchdb"
    environment:
      - "COUCHDB_USER="
      - "COUCHDB_PASSWORD="
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - "basic"
  cli:
    container_name: "cli"
    image: "hyperledger/fabric-tools"
    tty: true
    environment:
      - "GOPATH=/opt/gopath"
      - "CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info"
      - "CORE_PEER_ID=cli"
      - "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051"
      - "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP"
      - "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp"
      - "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
      - "CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10"
    working_dir: "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer"
    command: "/bin/bash"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/:/host/var/run/"
      - "./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/"
      - "./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/"
      - "./config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/config/"
    depends_on:
      - "orderer.example.com"
      - "peer0.org1.example.com"
      - "peer0.org2.example.com"
    networks:
      - "basic"
```

All docker containers are created successfully,

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
614685a858c0        hyperledger/fabric-tools     "/bin/bash"              18 hours ago        Up 18 hours                                                          cli
cead74ff3acf        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        18 hours ago        Up 18 hours         0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
abd07c877081        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        18 hours ago        Up 18 hours         0.0.0.0:10201->10201/tcp                         peer0.org2.example.com
70ac639b1b7a        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours         4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
e8d04f5cac45        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                18 hours ago        Up 18 hours         0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
3fafc99fe92d        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours         0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
c9b830eecf8a        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours         7054/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8054->8054/tcp                 ca.org2.example.com
```

when I go inside peer0.org1.example.com or cli container and run 'peer channel..' commands its working fine without issues...

```
root@cead74ff3acf:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric# peer channel list
2020-03-04 07:55:39.000 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Channels peers has joined:
```

but when I go inside peer0.org2.example.com container and run them I'm getting the below error,

```
root@abd07c877081:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric# peer channel list
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org2.example.com:10201: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.23.0.6:10201: connect: connection refused"
```

some warnings shown from peer0.org2 logs are,

```
[gossip.gossip] NewGossipService -> WARN 017 External endpoint is empty, peer will not be accessible outside of its organization

[gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 103 Failed obtaining connection for , PKIid:1fff29d8bd80fe1df86bbd7b23f14059a0ad1ac10fd0e790b133d6f84433087d reason: context deadline exceeded

[comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 122 unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2020-03-03T14:50:08.415Z grpc.peer_address=127.0.0.1:40334 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=160.19µs
[gossip.comm] func1 -> WARN 123 127.0.0.1:7051, PKIid:1fff29d8bd80fe1df86bbd7b23f14059a0ad1ac10fd0e790b133d6f84433087d isn't responsive: EOF
```

Can you please identify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS` on your peer, to let it actually listen on port `10201`.

When customizing ports, you need to make sure to override all relevant configurations, see: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/sampleconfig/core.yaml